# React-Native iOS does not display local images only when deployed with fastlane

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, fastlane

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.0.1
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1 Pro
    Memory: 409.86 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 19.7.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/node
    Yarn: Not Found
    npm: 9.5.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2023.03.06.00 - /opt/homebrew/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.12.0 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.1, iOS 16.1, macOS 13.0, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK: Not Found
  IDEs:
    Android Studio: 2021.3 AI-213.7172.25.2113.9123335
    Xcode: 14.1/14B47b - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
  Languages:
    Java: 11.0.12 - /usr/bin/javac
  npmPackages:
    u/react-native-community/cli: Not Found
    react: 18.0.0 => 18.0.0 
    react-native: 0.69.7 => 0.69.7 
    react-native-macos: Not Found
  npmGlobalPackages:
    *react-native*: Not Found
```

For some reason when my app is published via fastlane my local images dont work. My assets folder is declared in my build scripts and it is present in my Copy Resources section of Build Phases in Xcode. Moreover when I build my app in release scheme through Xcode images load fine, however when published with fastlane they dont work. If I archive and push a build to appstore connect using Xcode, the images are also displayed fine.

Heres my build script

```
"react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest ./ios"
```

The problem seems to come from fastlane, and Im not sure what to do.

Here is my fastfile code below.

```
default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do
  desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
  lane :beta do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "myApp.xcodeproj")
    get_certificates( # Create or get certificate, and install it
      output_path: "./builds" # Download certificate in the build folder (you don't need to create the folder)
    )
    get_provisioning_profile( # Create or get provisioning profile
      output_path: "./builds",  # Download provisioning profile in the build folder
      filename: "provisioning.mobileprovision" # Rename the local provisioning profile
    )
    update_project_provisioning( # Set the project provisioning profile (related in Xcode to the General > Signing Release section)
      xcodeproj: "myApp.xcodeproj",
      target_filter: "myApp", # Name of your project
      profile: "./builds/provisioning.mobileprovision",
      build_configuration: "Release"
    )
    update_project_team( # Set the right team on your project
      teamid: CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:team_id)
    )
    build_app(
      workspace: "myApp.xcworkspace", 
      scheme: "myApp",    
      clean: true,
      export_method: "app-store",
      export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
            CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier) => CredentialsManager::AppfileConfig.try_fetch_value(:app_identifier) + " AppStore" # Value of this parameter is the name of the Provisioning Profile. By default, it will be "{bundleId} AppStore"
        }
      },
      build_path: "./builds",
      output_directory: "./builds"
      )
    upload_to_testflight
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing it. Has to do with my ios/assets folder being linked to the project. Not sure which of these steps fixed things but I did the following in chronological order after restarting my laptop.

1. Changed build script to:
   `"react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios' --assets-dest ios"`.
2. deleted ios/assets folder in Xcode (selected move items to trash).
3. Ran build script, regenerated ios/assets folder.
4. Dragged ios/assets folder into Xcode linking folder, selected copy files when necessary.
5. Clean iOS build folder.
6. Deployed project via fastlane.

I believe the fix came from deleting assets folder and relinking, but anyone with more expertise can confirm.